# How to check which field are inserted when a select change using selenium

Tags: select, selenium, input, onchange

i need to know how to check what changes in a page when an option from select input is clicked. This is select input:

```
<select onchange="showCategory('category', 'carextras', 'company_ad', 'err_category');suggestCategory(document.formular.subject.value, this.value, 'subject-warning');" name="category" id="category">
```

clicking on an option, javascript will create different input type ( text, select and other) in function of what user clicks. I need to know how to get which input are inserted in page. Can someone help me? can someone give me a suggest? thanks!!! :)

SOLVED ( bad way ) ,thanks to JacekM, in this way:

```
WebElement cat =(new WebDriverWait(d, 1))
                .until(new ExpectedCondition<WebElement>(){
                    @Override
                    public WebElement apply(WebDriver d) {
                        return d.findElement(By.id("categoria"));
                    }}); 
        Select allCategory = new Select(cat);
        File f = new File("ebay1.txt");
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(f);
        pw.write("Categoria\n\t\tSottocategoria\n\t\t\t\tCampi\n");
        List<WebElement> categorie = allCategory.getOptions(); 
        for(int i=1;i<3;i++){
            pw.append(categorie.get(i).getText()+"\n");
            categorie.get(i).click();
            WebElement subcat =(new WebDriverWait(d, 1))
                    .until(new ExpectedCondition<WebElement>(){
                        @Override
                        public WebElement apply(WebDriver d) {
                            return d.findElement(By.id("sottocategoria"));
                        }}); 
            Select allSubCategory = new Select(subcat);
            List<WebElement> sottocategorie = allSubCategory.getOptions();
            sottocategorie.get(0).click();
            for(int j=1;j<sottocategorie.size();j++){
                List<WebElement> before = d.findElements(By.tagName("input"));
                List<WebElement> before_select = d.findElements(By.tagName("select"));
                List<WebElement> before_textarea = d.findElements(By.tagName("textarea"));
                List<String> before_inv = new ArrayList<String>();
                List<String> after_inv = new ArrayList<String>();
                for(WebElement bef : before){
                    if(bef.isDisplayed()){
                        String id = bef.getAttribute("id");
                        List<WebElement> labels = d.findElements(By.tagName("label"));
                        for(WebElement lab : labels){
                            if(lab.getAttribute("for").equals(id)){
                                before_inv.add(lab.getText());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                for(WebElement bef : before_select){
                    if(bef.isDisplayed()){
                        String id = bef.getAttribute("id");
                        List<WebElement> labels = d.findElements(By.tagName("label"));
                        for(WebElement lab : labels){
                            if(lab.getAttribute("for").equals(id)){
                                before_inv.add(lab.getText());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                for(WebElement bef : before_textarea){
                    if(bef.isDisplayed()){
                        String id = bef.getAttribute("id");
                        List<WebElement> labels = d.findElements(By.tagName("label"));
                        for(WebElement lab : labels){
                            if(lab.getAttribute("for").equals(id)){
                                before_inv.add(lab.getText());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                sottocategorie.get(j).click();
                pw.append("\t\t"+sottocategorie.get(j).getText()+"\n");


                List<WebElement> after = d.findElements(By.tagName("input"));
                List<WebElement> after_select = d.findElements(By.tagName("select"));
                List<WebElement> after_textarea = d.findElements(By.tagName("textarea"));
                for(WebElement aft : after){
                    if(aft.isDisplayed()){
                        String id = aft.getAttribute("id");
                        List<WebElement> labels = d.findElements(By.tagName("label"));
                        for(WebElement lab : labels){
                            if(lab.getAttribute("for").equals(id)){
                                after_inv.add(lab.getText());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                for(WebElement aft : after_select){
                    if(aft.isDisplayed()){
                        String id = aft.getAttribute("id");
                        List<WebElement> labels = d.findElements(By.tagName("label"));
                        for(WebElement lab : labels){
                            if(lab.getAttribute("for").equals(id)){
                                after_inv.add(lab.getText());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                for(WebElement aft : after_textarea){
                    if(aft.isDisplayed()){
                        String id = aft.getAttribute("id");
                        List<WebElement> labels = d.findElements(By.tagName("label"));
                        for(WebElement lab : labels){
                            if(lab.getAttribute("for").equals(id)){
                                after_inv.add(lab.getText());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                List<String> finale = new ArrayList<String>();
                for(String fin : after_inv){
                    if(!before_inv.contains(fin)){
                        finale.add(fin);
                    }
                }
                for(String fin:finale){
                    pw.append("\t\t\t\t"+fin.replace(":", "")+"\n");
                }
                sottocategorie.get(0).click();
            }
        }

        pw.close();
```

Comment: Does the input type(text,select and other) have id's associated to them?

Comment: no, if you want to see the page is : https://annunci.ebay.it/pubblica-annuncio

Comment: Hmm..I don't think there is a way by which you can check this without having any identifiers for the elements. At most, you can look for the corresponding label (example tire) and check whether there is a corresponding select box for. That way you make it relative to that label

Comment: i've see that when i click on subcategory, the elements that appear has style="display:block;". is there a way to get all element in function of style? something driver.findElement(By.xpath()) or By.style ( this is not existent )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first glance at the page you provided it seems that all elements are present on the page, they are just hidden using style="display:none". Therefore you can check the element's style or visibility.

```
String style = element.getAttribute("style");
boolean visible = element.isDisplayed();
```

If it's too difficult to specify all elements manually you may try

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//some/xpath")).findElements(By.xpath(".//*"));
```

to obtain all elements under //some/xpath and call the methods I mentioned above in the loop. You could create a list of same size that would store only boolean values - the results obtained via element.isDisplayed() method. Then you could compare the booleans with the current state of elements to see which of them have changed.

You could also store all invisible elements in array, and then every time you click something on page - iterate through them and see which one of them changed.

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//some/xpath")).findElements(By.xpath(".//*"));
List<WebElement> invisibles = new ArrayList<WebElement>();

for (WebElement elem : elements)
{
   if (!elem.isDisplayed())
   {
      invisibles.add(elem)
   }
}

//...

for (WebElement elem : invisibles)
{
   if (elem.isDisplayed())
   {
      //element has appeared
   }
}
```

The problem with this solution is that it will only handle elements appearing on the page, not disappearing ones.

Comment: i solve using your suggest, accepted for this :) if you want see my solution see edit :)

Comment: i know.. this isn't the best solution.. but for now it works ;)